# How to exit (close) a mobile flex application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex-mobile

I want to exit ( close ) programmatically a mobile flex application when clicking a Button. What is the ActionScript for that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
```

Explained here: [Application launching and exit options](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=app_launch_1.html).

Comment: check these links if it helps - 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218166/how-do-i-exit-or-suspend-a-flex-4-5-iphone-application-through-code                                            2. http://forums.adobe.com/thread/870733

Answer (score 4):

On Android you can do

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
```

On iOS, this is not possible. http://forums.adobe.com/message/4347689